# Rails 4: Is it possible to remove the call to a nested model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, attributes, nested-attributes

Suppose I have two classes like the following:

```
# has attribute name
class Foo
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :bar
end

# has attribute bing
class Bar

end
```

Is it possible in Rails to somehow easily remove the need to call attributes belonging to the nested class (in this case `Bar`). That is, is it possible to do the following?

```
my_foo.name
my_foo.bing
```

Would I need to create instance methods for each `Bar` attribute in `Foo`?

Further, is it possible to to create a new relation that's set up in this way without having to pass in an explicit parameters hash?

```
my_foo = Foo.new(name: "my_foo_name", bing: "my_foo.bar.bing")
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [delegate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) method.

For a defined association `bar`, delegate getter `name` attribute to `bar`:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :bar
  delegate :name, to: :bar
end
```

As for your second question, yes you can delegate setters `name=` and `bing=` to `bar` as shown above.  You'd have to ensure that the associated object is created before assignment is done, otherwise you'd get a "Undefined method ... for NilClass" error.

Please see referenced [delegate documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) for further details.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, I can't up-vote you enough! I would like to add that I am using the [slightly less well known] `after_initialize` callback in my model to ensure that my associated object is available